Conditions for inequallity $\text{dist}(x,\partial A) \geq \text{dist}(x,X\setminus A)$.
Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $A\subseteq X$ open. For all $x\in X$, I proved that
$$
  \text{dist}(x,\partial A) \geq \text{dist}(x,X\setminus A).
$$
For this, I use the hypothesis of $A$ is open. I'm searching for an example which show that this condition is needed.

You don't really need any hypothesis. Let $A\subset X$ be a general subset. Given $x\in\text{int}(A)$, your proof for an open $A$ works all the same. If $x\in A\setminus\text{int}(A)\subset\partial A$, it is clear that $\text{dist}(x,\partial A)=0$. But, as for any $\epsilon>0$, $B(x,\epsilon)\cap (X\setminus A)\neq\emptyset$,
$$\text{dist}(x,X\setminus A)\leq \epsilon$$
for every $\epsilon>0$. Hence, $\text{dist}(x,X\setminus A)=0$, which in particular yields the desired inequality. As for $x\in X\setminus A$, the RHS is obviously $0$ so there is nothing to prove.

I'm not sure how to use previous statement in the first part. Could you provide more details, please? For the proof of the inequality, I use the fact that $\partial A \subseteq X \setminus A$.
